# ¿Puede generarse una dependencia transitiva a partir de un conjunto intermedio de atributos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Si tenemos una tabla que representa la entidad "Estudiantes" y contiene los siguientes atributos:

#IdEstudiante | Nombre | Edad | Ciudad | CódigoPostal | Barrio

Siendo "IdEstudiante" la clave primaria, podemos analizar las dependencias entre los atributos. Si la combinación de los atributos "Ciudad" y "Barrio" nos permite determinar el "CódigoPostal", ¿podría considerarse una dependencia transitiva?

Para ejemplificar mejor mi duda, identifico la dependencia transitiva de la siguiente manera:

```
IdEstudiante -> Ciudad
IdEstudiante -> Barrio
{Ciudad, Barrio} -> CódigoPostal
IdEstudiante -> {Ciudad, Barrio} -> CódigoPostal
```

Entonces, ¿es posible tener una dependencia transitiva a partir de un conjunto de atributos?

Answer (score 2):

Pues la respuesta corta es no. Simplemente porque no tienes ninguna garantía de que el servicio postal no decida cambiar el CP en mitad de un barrio o asignar al mismo barrio de la misma cuidad dos códigos distintos dependiendo la calle o del número de la edificación en la calle, por ejemplo.

Si te refieres al caso ideal de, por ejemplo, la letra del DNI o el dígito de control de las cuentas bancarias, ¿merece la pena guardar ese dato calculado? Pues yo te diría que sí, porque precisamente está ahí para evitar errores en la transmisión o almacenamiento del dato.

Desde la perspectiva de un programador o un administrador de bases de datos, porque los matemáticos y demás teóricos juegan en otra liga, la normalización se estudia para que diseñemos las bases de datos con una redundancia mínima que evite futuras inconsistencias de datos. Pero también tenemos que ser prácticos porque, a diferencia de los teóricos, tenemos que desarrollar sistemas de gestión de la información que sean fáciles de desarrollar y, sobre todo, de mantener.

Te animo a que, ante este tipo de dudas, hagas el proceso completo y te plantees las consultas con las que explotarás los datos almacenados en esa estructura de datos. Un exceso de normalización simplemente exigirá más combinaciones de tablas o JOINs. Tú decides hasta qué punto le quieres complicar la vida en el futuro a tu equipo y a ti mismo, cuando no recordéis cómo lo habéis implementado. Mantenerlo simple, siempre será la mejor opción.

Conclusión: guarda esa información que facilita el usuario. A tiempo estarás de ignorarla o de hacer las comprobaciones que consideres convenientes.